# Python 2.7: Pandas datetime does not work for future dates?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas

I was trying to convert a DataFrame column (string) into `datetime` format when I encountered a ValueError. Here is a reproducible code (and the error) using a string instead of an DataFrame column:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.to_datetime('2007-08-17', format='%Y-%m-%d') #Works fine
Timestamp('2007-08-17 00:00:00')

>>> pd.to_datetime('2557-08-17', format='%Y-%m-%d') # Throws Error
ValueError: time data '2557-08-17' does match format specified
```

Is this a genuine issue or am I doing something wrong? How can this be fixed?

Comment: That's because your provided date is greater than `pd.Timestamp.max = "2262-04-11"`.  How far in the future are you looking to go?  The docstring of `pd.to_datetime` mentions this.

Comment: @wflynny I did not know that there was a max limit. Thanks for that info. These dates are (most probably) junk values flowing through my data, but I would prefer to not have any hiccups in the program nevertheless.

Comment: if the values are junk, you can just do something like `df.loc[:, df.date_col > pd.Timestamp.max.isoformat()] = pd.NaT`.  The method `pd.to_datetime` can accept NaN/NaT values.

Comment: @wflynny Setting the junk values to pd.NaT was really useful for my context. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob

Here are ways to represent data outside of the bounds (which are from Timestamp('1677-09-22 00:12:43.145225') to Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807') ).

The recommended way to do computations outside of the TimeStamp bounds is to use a PeriodIndex.