# Add time in pandas beyond year 2262

Tags: python, pandas, time, timestamp

I would like to add months to date in pandas. They may exceed beyond year 2262. There is a solution for relatively small number of months:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.Timestamp('2018-01-22 00:00:00') + np.timedelta64(12, 'M')
```

which results in

```
Timestamp('2019-01-22 05:49:12')
```

However, when I add larger number (which, as a result, exceeds year 2262):

```
pd.Timestamp('2018-01-22 00:00:00') + np.timedelta64(3650, 'M')
```

Python does return result:

```
Timestamp('1737-09-02 14:40:26.290448384')
```

How to cope with this?

Comment: hit the upper boundary .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036092/python-2-7-pandas-datetime-does-not-work-for-future-dates

Answer (score 1):

#### `datetime`

Pandas.Timestamp aims to handle much finer time resolution down to the nanosecond.  This precision takes up enough of the 64 bits allocated to it that it can only go up to the year 2262.  However, `datetime.datetime` does not have this limitation and can go up to year `9999`.  If you start working with `datetime` objects instead of `Timestamp` objects, you'll lose some functionality but you will be able to go beyond `2262`.

Also, your number of months also went beyond the maximum number of days for a `Timedelta`

Let's begin by picking a more reasonable sized number of months that is a nice multiple of 48 (Four years).

```
d = pd.Timedelta(48, 'M')
```

And our date

```
t = pd.Timestamp('2018-01-22')
```

A multiple that represents how many times our 48 months fits inside the desired 3650 months.

```
m = 3650 / 48
```

Then we can use `to_pydatetime` and `to_pytimedelta`

```
t.to_pydatetime() +  d.to_pytimedelta() * m

datetime.datetime(2322, 3, 24, 14, 15, 0, 1)
```